# Spock + Drools Testing

Tags: groovy, drools, spock

I have a question regarding SPOCK + Drools testing. Here's the thing,

```
KnowledgeBuilder builder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
```

That line of code works absolutely fine,inside a JUnit test case. It doesn't inside SPOCK.

I get the following exception,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/xjc/Options
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.xjc.Options
    ... 3 more
```

What could be the problem? Is it drools related? Unable to get ny head riund the problem. Any help is much appreciated :)

**Update:**

I am running the test inside a webapp w/o it being deployed(if that makes any sense :)). I added the jar to the classpath(not WEB-INF/libs) and it is working fine now.

Comment: What does your test look like?

Comment: Looks like a Groovy problem, rather than a Spock problem. Perhaps Groovy isn't set up correctly. How are you executing the test?

Comment: Just added the required jar to the classpath and sge seems fine now :) Thanks for the help guys :)

Comment: What was the lib you were missing?

Comment: Good question. I'd also like to know the answer. @Avinash : Can you answer your SO question please?

Comment: He has already answered. Appropriate lib was added to classpath.

Comment: @Opal, he didn't answer WHAT library that was missing...

Comment: Ok, so still waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Although OP states in his update that the problem got fixed by adding appropriate libs to classpath, he does not specify the libs.

I believe this issue gets fixed by adding the following to your dependencies

```
build('com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.1')
build('com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.1')
```

Comment: I have the same problem but this dependencies did not helped me. Does anyone know what should be a solution? I am using 6.1.0.Final version of both drools and knowledge-api

Comment: @ivan In my case the **Drools version was 5.5-something**. I'd recommend you to post a new question with Drools 6.1.0 specific tags. And also link you new question to this one stating that it's not a duplicate.